# Angular ng-model not working with checkbox for initial value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular v1.5x

There are many other questions that sound similar, but none of them solved my problem, so I'm adding this to try to save someone else time.

**This DOESN't Work:**

```
app.controller("Controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.foo.bar = "true"
}

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo.bar" />
```

The two-way binding actually is working. But the checkbox will not be checked on first load.

Answer (score 2):

**This DOES work:**

```
app.controller("Controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.foo.bar = true
}

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo.bar" />
```

Notice that in this version, the value of `foo.bar` is a boolean. I learned the hard way (after hours of frustration) that `ng-model` on a checkbox does not work with any truthy value.

**Bonus tip:**

This is pointed out in many other questions, but it's worth repeating here. Angular is known to behave unpredictably sometimes when you bind directly to primitives instead of properties. Translation: Always include a `.` in your `ng-model`.

Good: `ng-model="foo.bar"`

Bad: `ng-model="foobar"`